# Multiple conditional branches in Serilog expression

Tags: conditional-statements, serilog

We've started using Serilog to generate structure logs for our application. Using [Serilog Expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) we've been able to generate the following JSON, which is fairly cool as far as logging goes.

```
{
    "@t": "2022-02-11T15:57:57.6087361+01:00",
    "@m": "GET Request received on API endpoint /foo",
    "@l": "Info",
    "SourceContext": "Company.API.FooController",
    "ActionId": "bd248542-138b-4053-9d50-b9e62e0ab1fd",
    "ActionName": "Company.API.FooController.GetFoo (Company.API)",
    "RequestId": "0HMFDDRDSMUUI:00000001",
    "RequestPath": "/foo",
    "SpanId": "|85c9c2db-489a260ce2c6915e.",
    "TraceId": "85c9c2db-489a260ce2c6915e",
    "ParentId": "",
    "ConnectionId": "0HMFDDRDSMUUI",
    "ThreadId": 7,
    "ContextFieldA": "ValueA",
    "ContextFieldB": "ValueA"
}
```

These log events are generated using the following expression, which is read from the environment variables:

```
"{ {@t, @m, @r, @l: if @l = 'Information' then 'Info' else @l, @x, ..@p} }\n"
```

However we'd like to map the other log levels to short-hands as well. Such as `Warning` to `Warn` etc. How would we go about adding multiple if-else branches to this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly simple actually. Multiple branches can be done exactly like one might expect:

```
"{ {@t, @m, @r, @l: if @l = 'Information' then 'Info' 
    else if @l = 'Warning' then 'Warn' else @l, @x, ..@p} }\n"
```